# nodemon not loading environment variables

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, dotenv

The following is in my `gulpfile.js`:

```js
const nodemon = require('nodemon')

const server = nodemon({
    script: './src/index.js',
    ext: 'hbs json js css',
    require: 'dotenv/config',
    dotenv_config_path: './config/.env',
    stdout: false // without this line the stdout event won't fire
})
```

I am looking to duplicate the exact same behavior as the `dev` script in the `package.json` file:

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest --watch",
    "dev": "nodemon -r dotenv/config ./src/index.js dotenv_config_path=./config/.env -e js,hbs,json,css",
    "debug": "nodemon --inspect -r dotenv/config ./src/index.js dotenv_config_path=./config/.env -e js,hbs,json,css"
  },
```

For one reason or another it seems that `gulp` is not registering the environment variables defined in the `.env` file. Although the line below works just fine when ran with `npm run dev`:

`nodemon -r dotenv/config ./src/index.js dotenv_config_path=./config/.env -e js,hbs,json,css`

Comment: should `dotenv_config_path` have a space in its value?

Comment: No it shouldn't that was a copy/paste issue

Answer (score 1):

You may need to add `export` to your environment vars and load them before running `nodemon`:

**vars.env**

```
export ENV_FIRST="J"
export ENV_LAST="Doe"
```

**package.json**

```
"scripts": {
  "dev": "source vars.env; nodemon ..."
  ...
}
```